# UI modal dialog getting added to a new DIV tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This might be an easy question for you guys but it got really difficult for a newbie like me. I have several divs which I create through ng-repeat, when I click over the div I wish to see a modal window with some content in it. Right now I am able to get the popup working and also the data, however the instead of the the modal window showing up inside the div, it is creating a div of its own. I am using the modal window as a separate module and injecting the same into my controller.

**THE MAIN APP CONTROLLER**

```
 var app = angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','mddmodal']);

    app.controller('MddController',function ($scope, $interval, $modal, $log) {

            $scope.showInfo = function (index) {
                var exchangeCode = $scope.entries[index];
                console.log( ">>>>>>> showInfo " + index );
                $scope.open( 'sm', index );
            }

            $scope.hideInfo = function (index) {
                var exchangeCode = $scope.entries[index];
                /*$scope.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');*/
            }

            $scope.items = [];

            $scope.open = function (window_size, index ) {

                console.log("Clicked on open +++++ " + window_size + " index " + index );
                $scope.items.push( "index" + index );

                $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/controllers/_mdd_modal_impl.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    size: window_size,
                    resolve: {
                        items: function () {
                            return $scope.items;
                        }
                    }
                });
        };
```

**PARTIAL VIEW**

```
    <div class="padding-from-sides" >
        <div class="row top-buffer" ng-show="dataLoaded">
            <div ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-model="entry" class="col-md-1" ng-click="showInfo($index)" ng-mouseleave="hideInfo($index)">
                <!--{{entry.errors}}-->
                <div square-draw component-id="entry.exchangeCode" component-name="entry.exchangeName" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**MODAL HTML**

```
    <body ng-app='mddmodal'>
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <li>
                        <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                    </li>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <!--    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>-->
</div>
</body>
```

**MODAL JS**

```
var mdd_modal = angular.module('mddmodal',['ui.bootstrap']);

mdd_modal.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

The problem that I am facing right now is the popup for the modal is getting created outside the ng-repeat div, How do I control the modal so that I can get the modal inside the ng-repeat div.

For example :

```
<ng repeat div>
    one entry of the square draw directive
    modal on click
<close div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide us fiddle or plunker..??

Answer (score 0):

Third party Apps are good at placing things in unexpected places.  I use a third party popup (ColorBox) that creates 2 divs required for it to work, However in an ASP.NET  Web App it places these elements outside the form.  So to make the code work I had to add this per their FAQ, to relocate the offending div's:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#colorbox, #cboxOverlay").appendTo('form:first');
});
```

Something similar may work for you.